# How to write raw binary data using Indy TCP Client in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, tcpclient, indy

Using Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.3.

I have a `DynamicArray<uint8_t> myData` object. I want to send/write its raw binary content (bytes) to a server using the `TIdTcpClient` component. I'm going about it like this:

```
TIdTcpClient tcpClient1;
// Bla Bla Bla
tcpClient1->IOHandler->Write(rawData);
```

Where `rawData` should be of type `TIdBytes` or `TIdStream`

So basically, it boils down to the following: How to convert `myData` object to a `rawData` type of either `TIdBytes` or `TIdStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `TIdStream` has not been part of Indy in a VERY VERY LONG time, which makes me wonder if you are using a very old version of Indy, not the one that shipped with C++Builder 10.3.  Indy has supported the RTL's standard `TStream` class for a very long time.

That being said...

`TIdBytes` is an alias for `System::DynamicArray<System::Byte>`, where `System::Byte` is an alias for `unsigned char`, which is the same size and sign-ness as `uint8_t` (depending on compiler, `uint8_t` might even just be an alias for `unsigned char`).

So, the simplest solution, *without* having to make a separate copy of your data, is to simply type-cast it, eg:

```
tcpClient1->IOHandler->Write(reinterpret_cast<TIdBytes&>(myData));
```

This is technically *undefined behavior*, since `DynamicArray<uint8_t>` and `DynamicArray<Byte>` are unrelated types (unless `uint8_t` and `Byte` are both aliases for `unsigned char`), but it will work in your case since it is the same underlying code behind both arrays, and `uint8_t` and `Byte` have the same underlying memory layout.

Alternatively, the next simplest solution, *without* copying data or invoking undefined behavior, is to use Indy's `TIdReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream` class in `IdGlobal.hpp`, eg:

```
TIdReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream *ms = new TIdReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream(&myData[0], myData.Length);
try {
    tcpClient1->IOHandler->Write(ms);
}
__finally {
    delete ms;
}
```

Or:

```
{
auto ms = std::make_unique<TIdReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream>(&myData[0], myData.Length);
tcpClient1->IOHandler->Write(ms.get());
}
```

Otherwise, the final solution is to just copy the data into a `TIdBytes`, eg:

```
{
TIdBytes bytes;
bytes.Length = myData.Length;

memcpy(&bytes[0], &myData[0], myData.Length);
or:
std::copy(myData.begin(), myData.end(), bytes.begin());

tcpClient1->IOHandler->Write(bytes);
}
```

Comment: According to the Indy documentation that shipped with C++ Builder 10.3, one of the overloads for `IOHandler`'s `Write` method is `TIdIOHandler.Write (TIdStream, Int64, Boolean)`.

According to `stdint.h`, `uint8_t` is not defined as `typedef unsigned char` but rather `typedef unsigned __int8` where `__int8` is an extended integral type of fixed length. That being said, I don't think the undefined behavior will be a problem. Even better is to replace my `uint8_t`s with `System::Byte`.

Comment: Indy's documentation is very old, it hasn't been updated in a long time. In this case, `TIdIOHandler.Write (TIdStream, Int64, Boolean)` is now `TIdIOHandler.Write (TStream, Int64, Boolean)`